# How To fix A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<Space>'

Tags: flutter, dart

> Here's my code

````
Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: edge),
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: spaceProvider.getRecommendedSpaces(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  List<Space> data = ```snapshot.data; 

                  int index = 0;

                  return Column(
                    children: data.map((item) {
                      index++;
                      return Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: index == 1 ? 0 : 30),
                          child: SpaceCard(item));
                    }).toList(),
                  );
                }
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
````

> The error is

```
List<Space> data = snapshot.data;
```

> That code is error and it's called A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List'.Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'List'.

Comment: is snapshot.data is List?

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon what kind of object is in the Object?. If the Object? contains something of type List<space>, then you might do something like:

```
var data = (snapshot.data as List<Space>);
```

If it's some kind of collection or enumerable that is not a List<>, then you might use LINQ to do the following:

```
var data = ((System.Collections.IEnumerable)snapshot.data).Cast<Space>().ToList();
```

If the kind of object is not even based on class Space, you'd have to map it manually, there are numerous clever ways of doing that in C# including cast operators, but the simplest is as follows:

```
var data = new List<Space>();
foreach (var src in ((System.Collections.IEnumerable)snapshot.data)) {
    var dest = new Space();
    dest.prop1 = src.prop1;
    dest.prop2 = src.prop2;
    ...
    data.Add(dest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: edge,
              ),
              child: FutureBuilder<List<Space>>(
                future: spaceProvider.getRecommendedSpaces(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    List<Space> data = snapshot.data as List<Space>;

                    int index = 0;

                    return Column(
                      children: data.map((item) {
                        index++;
                        return Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: index == 1 ? 0 : 30,
                          ),
                          child: SpaceCard(item),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    );
                  }
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).